# Highcharts: Pyramid graph, but sideways?

Tags: graph, highcharts

Please take a look at https://img42.com/q6HKj

The client basically needs a pyramid graph, but with the pyramid turned on it's side, with the top to the right?  Is this achievable?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately at this moment inverted pyramid is not build-in, but you can contact with us by email (support@highcharts.com) and we will forward your message to developers who prepares custom implementsion. Meantime you can post your suggestion in our [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)

Comment: Or, perhaps you can use the polygon series to draw it yourself: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.polygon  | OTOH, this is an essentially useless chart type, client request or not...  :)